# Instagram Latest post API suddenly stopped working

Tags: json, api, ssl, curl, instagram

My instagram feed was working fine but it has stopped working. I am trying to find a solution. First I assume the issue is related to SSL, I even got SSL certificate for my website. But doesn't seem to work. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Output showed latest image posted on instagram and now shows nothing.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPuxg.png)

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 no-padding">
<div class="insta_img">
  <?php
                $instagram_id = get_field('instagram_id', 'option') ? get_field('instagram_id', 'option') : '';
                $access_token = get_field('instagram_access_token', 'option') ? get_field('instagram_access_token', 'option') : '';
                $url = "https://www.instagram.com/{$instagram_id}/?__a=1";
                curl_close($ch);  
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                $json = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                $data = json_decode($json);
                $data = $data->user->media->nodes;

                $text = $data[0]->caption;

                $created_time = $data[0]->date ;

                $images = $data[0]->thumbnail_src;
                /

            ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $images; ?>"  alt="instagram"/>
  <div class="insta_content"><?php echo $text; ?>
    <dt><?php echo date('d/m/Y', $created_time); ?></dt>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instagram lately made some changes to their API due to the Facebook privacy saga. You might want to check their news or changelog for that.

Comment: @RuChernChong Thank you for your reply. I will have a look at their changelog. I hope they have a solution soon.

Comment: You're not using the official API. You're basically just scraping the URL. So you should not rely on that method to always give you a predictable result. Also, why are you refererincing an access token that you never use?

Comment: @hermanschutte Thank you for your reply. I have commented that line. I was trying different urls so I forgot to comment it before posting here. As you have mentioned that it is not an official API, I noticed it too, the API was created by someone else. Is there a way to fetch the latest post from Instagram account using an offical API?

Comment: @sundasmunir yes, the endpoint you are looking for is this one: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`. More information available in the Instagram API docs: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: @hermanschutte Thank you again for your reply. I have used the endpoint that you have mentioned. But this is the error I am getting,

{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "data": [], "meta": {"code": 200}}

Is there a solution for that? My client status is Sandbox Mode, could that be a reason?

Comment: @sundasmunir in Sandbox Mode you will only be able to get data for Sandbox users. Are you using an access token for someone that is a user of your Sandboxed app?

Comment: @hermanschutte No I am not using access token for anyone else's app. I think, I am missing some point or not understanding it properly. I just want to display my Instagram's latest post with caption on my website. I created an App and that is in Sandbox mode. I used the the endpoint:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS TOKEN
But Instagram feed is still not working.

Comment: That is the correct endpoint to use. You will need to verify that the access token you are using is one that is authorized for your sandboxed app.

Comment: @hermanschutte Thank you for having time to look into my issue.
The access token seems to work fine as it is showing me information regarding my account. But the website is still not fetching any data. I will share the code, please have a look at it. If you find anything that should be changed please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not correctly parsing the response. For example, in that response there is no `user->media->nodes`. You will need to check the response you get from the endpoint, and then parse it correctly to get the images:

```
$access_token = get_field('instagram_access_token', 'option') ? get_field('instagram_access_token', 'option') : '';
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token={$access_token}";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$json = curl_exec($ch);                   
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($json);
$data = $data->data;

$text = $data[0]->caption->text;

$created_time = $data[0]->created_time;

$images = $data[0]->images->standard_resolution->url;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my problem, instagram's recent post is displayed on the website. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has disabled following capabilities (i.e., **deprecated** following API's) on 6th April 2018:

Follower List - to read the list of followers and followed-by users

Relationships - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf

Commenting on Public Content - to post and delete comments on a user’s behalf on public media

Likes - to like and unlike media on a user’s behalf

Subscriptions - to receive notifications when media is posted

Users Information - to search for and view users' public content
Some information on Public Content returned through hashtag and location 
search - Name, Bio, Comments, Commenters, Follower Count, Following Count, 
Post Count, and Profile Picture

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So that means there is no way that my Instagram's latest post can be fetched to my website.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Instagram did not deprecate the media recent feed for the _self endpoint. So it is still possible to retrieve your own latest posts.

Answer (score 0):

The access token is working fine. But the post are not visible on the website. The code that I am using is as follow:

```
$access_token = get_field('instagram_access_token', 'option') ? get_field('instagram_access_token', 'option') : '';
               $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token={$access_token}";

                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                $json = curl_exec($ch);                   
                curl_close($ch);

                $data = json_decode($json);
                $data = $data->user->media->nodes;


                $text = $data[0]->caption;

                $created_time = $data[0]->date ;

                $images = $data[0]->thumbnail_src;
```

Comment: The correct endpoint is: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=`

Comment: Ohh my mistake. Tried with this as well https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token={$access_token}
But it still doesn't work.